# Definition of a Limit epsilon delta

Tags: calculus

Why is it that the limit exists if: for all numbers epsilon (in the epsilon range close to L) => that there’s a delta (in the delta range close to a) and if this number Epsilon exists and it turns out that there is a delta for this epsilon then this implies that there is a limit? 
Why does the other way around not work as well? (it seems like from this definition that the y axis (epsilon range) is greater than the x-axis delta range according to the definition.

Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: "Why does the other way around not work as well?" What other way?

Comment: 0<|x-a|<\delta  implies that  |f(x)-L|<\epsilon            Why is it not reversed so that if for every epsilon we can find a delta then there is a limit

Comment: You mean to ask why it is not reversed so that:$$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\implies0<|x-a|<\delta$$?

Comment: yes that is what I wanted to ask

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ does not imply $0<|x-0|<\delta$, since we could have $x=k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer $k>\delta$.

Comment: because in this example the range of epsilon exists, but the range of delta doesn't exist?

Comment: Correct. The implication is only one direction, especially with periodic functions (and often others).

Comment: Okay thanks for the good example finally I feel like I understand limits a bit more :D

Comment: :-) No problem. Definition of the limit is quite a convoluted piece to knit together.

Answer (score 0):

hint:
[image]

This gif show the performance of $$\epsilon,\delta$$ . Hope it help you

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate any further?